# Using the dvi2tty package

Tags: packages, installing, package-options

I want to convert a `.dvi` file using `dvi2tty` but I don't know how. I downloaded the `dvi2tty` package, which contains only some `.tex` files and other extensions, and I can't see from where to start. Could you give me some pointers?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Did you have a look at the [manual](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/cgi-bin/manServer.pl/usr/share/man/man1/dvi2tty.1)?

Comment: `dvi2tty` is a very old tool that displays DVI files on “dumb” terminals. Its output is a *very* rough approximation of the printout. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you ! I have read the manuel but still don't know how to proceed should I integrate the name of my dvi file into div2tty.tex or what exactly ? :)

Comment: @egreg I have a dvi file that can't be viewed by miktex or any other tool so I want to partially convert it to a tex file so that I formulate it again, I suppose it's the only way to do it isn't it ?

Comment: you don't need dvi2tty.tex you need (and presumably already have in your tex distribution) dvi2tty.exe (as a windows executable) then if you have `myfile.dvi`  just run `dvi2tty myfile` on the commandline